# Angular. Trying to get a full PDF from the app but only the current view is printed

Tags: angular, angular15

I've created a new Angular app using Ionic, although without it I have the same problem, and I'm unable to print the whole content but the current view.

I need to print the whole content.

Somebody can help? I think it should have a simple solution, but after searching on other topics I didn't find a solution.

Here it is a Stackblick that may helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iovyou

And here you can find a demo about what I need to do: https://unidad-didactica-dcca0.web.app/tabs/session1

I expect to get a PDF file based on the full page, and containing all the styles (WYSIWYG)

[image]

Comment: Hi @KJ, how have you exported the page? I've already installed the Acrobat Edge extension but I'm unable to export the page into a PDF file. Sorry that's new to me.

Note: Reducing the scale is not an option, because I will need print much more data in more than one PDF page.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the CSS, but I'm not able to set a height 100%

Comment: Thanks @KJ. I think the issue is within Ionic and the overflows. So it's a CSS problem here, but I don't know hot fix it using Ionic

Comment: Ok @KJ, I will try in that way. Regards.